# How to add class to an element only on certain page using ng-class in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

It's seems to be a very simple question. But I've got stuck:

```html
<div ng-class="if we're on '/certainpage' : some-class"></div>
```

All I need is to show class only when we're on '/certainpage'.

Comment: Just use $scope.url = $location.url() to get current location in controller and then check it by `ng-class="{'some-class' : (url == "/certainPage") }"`

Comment: @M. Junaid Salaat, this solution works fine, thank you!

Comment: My Pleasure. Happy to help. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the location of Angular :

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location

```
var url = $location.url();
```

Don't forget to add the service to your directive.

```js
$scope.checkLocation() = function() {
  var url = $location.url();
  if (url = 'yourUrlToCheck')
    return true
  return false
}
```

```css
.red {
 color : red; 
}
```

```html
<div ng-class="{'red': checkLocation() }">Here is a div</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is `$location.path()` (`$location.url()` may not work if you have some querystring e.g. */certainpage?a=1*).

```
<div ng-class="{'some-class': isOnCertainPage()}"></div>
```

Then in your controller:

```
$scope.isOnCertainPage = function() {
    return $location.path() === "/certainpage";
};
```